# Treasure Hunt program in Java

Tags: java, computer-science

For a class I am in we have a program to write that asks a player to guess x and y coordinates until the treasure is found. The project consists of 2 files called Treasure.java and TreasureHunt.java which uses the Treasure class to play the game. The code that I have so far is...

```
package treasurehunt;

public class Treasure {

public int POSITIONS_PER_ROW = 20;
public int MAX_DISTANCE = 401;
private String name;
private int xLocation;
private int yLocation;
private Boolean found;


    public Treasure(){
     name = "";
     xLocation = 0;
     yLocation = 0;
     found = false;
    }

    public Treasure(String name){
        this.name = name;
        xLocation = 0;
        yLocation = 0;
        found = false;
    }

    public int getXLocation(){
        return xLocation;
    }

    public int getYLocation(){
        return yLocation;
    }

    public boolean isFound(){
        return found; 
    }

    public void hideTreasure(){
        xLocation = 1+(int)(Math.random()*POSITIONS_PER_ROW);
        yLocation = 1+(int)(Math.random()*POSITIONS_PER_ROW);
    }

    public int treasureStatus(int xStick , int yStick){
     if (xStick == xLocation && yStick == yLocation){
        return 0;
    } else if (xStick != xLocation || yStick != yLocation) {
        return Math.abs((yStick-yLocation)+(xStick-xLocation));           
    } else return MAX_DISTANCE;



}


}
```

---------------------------------------AND-------------------------------------------------

```
package treasurehunt;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TreasureHunt {

public static final int MAX_DISTANCE = 401;
public static final int POSITIONS_PER_ROW = 20;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Treasure gold = new Treasure();
    Treasure diamond = new Treasure();
    char playAgain = 0;

    gold.hideTreasure();
    diamond.hideTreasure();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Treasures have been hidden.");

    do{
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Enter x and y coordinates to search: ");
    int xStick = keyboard.nextInt();
    int yStick = keyboard.nextInt();

    int dist1 = diamond.treasureStatus(xStick, yStick);
    int dist2 = gold.treasureStatus(xStick , yStick);

    if (dist1 == 0 || dist1 == MAX_DISTANCE){
        System.out.println("Diamonds: FOUND!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Diamonds: " + dist1 + " away");
    }

    if (dist2 == 0 || dist2 == MAX_DISTANCE){
        System.out.println("Gold: FOUND!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Gold: " + dist2 + " away");
    }

    }while(!diamond.isFound() && !gold.isFound());




    do{
    System.out.println("Play again? y/n:");
    playAgain = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    }while(diamond.isFound() && gold.isFound());

}
}
```

When the program runs correctly it is supposed to look like this....

```
Treasures have been hidden.
Enter x and y coordinates to search: 17 11
Diamonds: 2 away
Gold: 9 away

Enter x and y coordinates to search: 17 13
Diamonds: FOUND!
Gold: 7 away

Enter x and y coordinates to search: 21 13
Diamonds: FOUND!
Gold: 9 away

Enter x and y coordinates to search: 17 16
Diamonds: FOUND!
Gold: 4 away

Enter x and y coordinates to search: 17 19
Diamonds: FOUND!
Gold: 1 away

Enter x and y coordinates to search: 18 19
Diamonds: FOUND!
Gold: FOUND!

It took you 6 tries to find 2 treasures.

Play again? y/n: n
```

My question is once you find the first treasure how do you keep it from changing "FOUND!" to not found when you guess coordinates for the second treasure. The code that I have now removes the "FOUND!" and changes it to # away every time you guess the coordinates for the second treasure. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In your `TreasureHunt` class, you could include two boolean variables to track the state of your treasure hunt. For example, `boolean isDiamondFound` and `boolean isGoldFound`. When you find the treasure, set the appropriate boolean variable to true. When printing, if the boolean is true, print FOUND, else print the distance to the treasure.

Comment: Actually it looks like Treasure implements a `found` boolean. Why don't you just set Treasure's `found = true`, and then, if isFound, print FOUND as described?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this (which is almost the same as your initial post). You need to update your Treasure class add a setFound method like this and change your hideTreasure method as follows.

```
// Set's the found 
public void setFound(boolean found) {
  this.found = found;
}

// Setting found to false on hide!
public void hideTreasure() {
  this.found = false;
  xLocation = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * POSITIONS_PER_ROW);
  yLocation = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * POSITIONS_PER_ROW);
}

// Finally update the main method to use the changes above.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Treasure gold = new Treasure();
    Treasure diamond = new Treasure();
    char playAgain = 0;

    gold.hideTreasure();
    diamond.hideTreasure();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Treasures have been hidden.");

    try {
      do {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out
            .print("Enter x and y coordinates to search: ");
        int xStick = keyboard.nextInt();
        int yStick = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (!diamond.isFound()) {
          int dist1 = diamond.treasureStatus(xStick,
              yStick);
          if (dist1 == 0 || dist1 == MAX_DISTANCE) {
            diamond.setFound(true);
            System.out.println("Diamonds: FOUND!");
          } else {
            System.out.println("Diamonds: " + dist1
                + " away");
          }
        }

        if (!gold.isFound()) {
          int dist2 = gold.treasureStatus(xStick,
              yStick);
          if (dist2 == 0 || dist2 == MAX_DISTANCE) {
            gold.setFound(true);
            System.out.println("Gold: FOUND!");
          } else {
            System.out.println("Gold: " + dist2
                + " away");
          }
        }
        if (diamond.isFound() && gold.isFound()) {
          System.out.println("Play again? y/n:");
          playAgain = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
          if (playAgain != 'Y' && playAgain != 'y') {
            System.exit(0);
          } else {
            diamond.hideTreasure();
            gold.hideTreasure();
          }
        }
      } while (true);
    } finally {
      keyboard.close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I somewhat understand what you are saying, but after using your help on the code the program still changes the "Found!" after guessing the coordinates of the second treasure. Once a treasure is found, the program should continue to say it's found until the second treasure is also found. Moving the coordinates should not re-hide the found treasure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use one flag(either int value or boolean) value. and you can change the values of the flag according to the treasure state either found or distance to tresure..

I think you can declare one variable like

```
int flag=0;
```

once you found the treasure set flag=1;

```
 if( flag=0)
 {
     String pout="write distance value here"
 }

 if(flag==1)
 {
    String pout="found !!";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You really just need to make `found` a permanent stopping point in the treasureStatus method. Right now you have a "Found" variable, but it's not doing you any good unless you make it an unchangeable stopping point in your code.

Something like this in the treasureStatus method...

```
 public int treasureStatus(int xStick , int yStick){
 if ((xStick == xLocation && yStick == yLocation) || found == true){
    return 0;
 } else if ...
```

This'll make it to where the method, `if found == true`, will  simply `return 0` each time, marking the Treasure as found.

(As a note, first time answering a Stack Overflow question, I apologize for my horrific formatting.)